# How to do ORs in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

What's the best way to do a query like this in MongoDB?

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE (a = 1 or b = 1) and (c = 2 or d = 2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$or](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) expression.

db.things.find( { $or : [ { a : 1}, { b : 1 } ], $or : [ { c : 2 }, { d : 2 } ] } )

Comment: Right idea but clearly the wrong answer. Test case: db.things.save({"b" : 1, "c" : 2}); db.things.find( { $or : [ { a : 1, b : 1 } , { c : 2, d : 2 } ] } );  Satisfies both halves of the and clause from above, but does not come back with your query.

Comment: @Gates VP: You're right indeed. Thanks for noticing, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**@Drew**, the correct answer for this query is the following:

`db.test.find( { $or : [ { a : 1}, { b : 1 } ], $or : [ { c : 2 }, { d : 2 } ] } )`

That's `a = 1 or b = 1` **and** `c = 2 or d = 2`. If you look at the code, you'll notice that you have two *or* clauses separated by a comma. When doing a find, the comma is effectively the *and* clause.

For docs on using the $or clause, see [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or).

Comment: Thanks, now I wonder how I use that with a the node-mongodb-native library. It is not a valid javascript object because it has two keys of the same name.

Comment: Also, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: OK, NodeJS and NodeMongo are really new. We're talking about a first commit on July 4th. Honestly I would just go to the github page and message the developers directly: http://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

Comment: You're not understanding how JS works. $or is a key in the object literal and you're providing that key twice, so the first one is being overwritten by the second